# exporting a java project in eclipse as a runnable JAR with has external references

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I made a program in `Eclipse` (on `Mac`) with a `main` method and `class` (which I called `run`). This program uses the `pdfbox` library which I imported and added to the `build path`. I am able to export this as a `runnable JAR` file on my computer that works fine. It seems to work on other `Mac` computers, but not on `Windows`.

I asked a friend to copy the individual `Java` files over and the only error he had was that it couldn't find the `pdfbox` library, so I think the error is something with the library when it's exported, I'm just not sure exactly what. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myeQS.png) a picture of the project in package explorer in case that helps.

Comment: The runnable JAR must also contain the content of the referenced library `pdfbox`. Alternatively, you can ship both JARs, but then it have to be run using the [classpath option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/219801/6505250).

Comment: try to create a lib subdirectory and copy the jar file there. Btw PDFBox is now at 2.0.7. Either it will work immediately, or you'll need to do what's in the previous comment.